# view move circulation

Tags: android, view, move

I have a question. I want to move a `View`(`FrameLayout`) from right to left(using layout function to locate the view's position), and I wish the view can appeared in right step by step, that is mean the view can circulation move in screen, disappear in left direction and appear in right direction, most same as Gallery, but not an image, It's a `View`(`FrameLayout`). Anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ViewFlipper** with animation.

Answer (score 0):

A full working example of view flipper can find from below link
http://blog.kerul.net/2011/07/viewflipper-examplea-simple-flashcard.html